# How to show a div for a while before second page load in iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with name ADD . and with this button I want to load a second page in iframe. the question is how can I show a loading div for 4 second before load second page in second ? I wrote some code but the code is not working correctly.

here is my snippet :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".adding").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#someFrame').html('<span class="loading">LOADING...</span>');
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#someFrame").attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));
    }, 3000);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="secondpage.html" class="adding">
  <div>ADD</div>
</a>

<iframe name="someFrame" id="someFrame" width="560" height="315"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".adding").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#iframeplace').html('<span class="loading">LOADING...</span>');

    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#iframeplace").html("<iframe name='someFrame' id='someFrame' width='560' height='315'></iframe>");
    }, 3000);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="secondpage.html" class="adding">
  <div>ADD</div>
</a>
<div id="iframeplace"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

iframe contents cannot be accessed directly.

Use it like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".adding").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var src = $(this).attr("href");
    $("#someFrame").contents().find("body").html('<span class="loading">LOADING...</span>');
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#someFrame").attr("src", src);
    }, 3000);

    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".adding").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#someFrame').css("background-image","url('http://www.downgraf.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/01-progress.gif')");
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#someFrame').css("background-image","none");
      $("#someFrame").attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));
    }, 1000);
  })
});
```

```css
span{
  z-index:999;
  color:black;
}
#someFrame{
  background-position:center;
  background-size:50px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="secondpage.html" class="adding">
  <div>ADD</div>
</a>

<iframe src="" name="someFrame" id="someFrame" width="400" height="200"></iframe>
```